# Get all attributes in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML like this:

```
<msg action="getDetails" class="2">
   <stamps msgtime="4/15/2014" ltq="2014-04-15">
       <dat la="get" />
   </stamps>
</msg>
```

How can I retrieve Dictionary of all the attributes and their corresponding values? The expected output should look this:

> action - getDetails
>   class - 2
>   msgtime - 4/15/2014
>   ltq - 2014-04-15
>   la - get

I can get it work for a particular level, but not for all child elements.

Comment: why you are prefering dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");

var attributes = xDoc.Descendants()
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => (string)x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

It would allow you to get an `IEnumerable<XElement>` of all of the elements, getting the attributes is something you have already done it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It I used Selman22's code and it worked fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Linq-to-XML` it is much easier to get the attribute and their values.

Sample usage

```
XElement cust = new XElement("PhoneNumbers",
new XElement("Phone",
    new XAttribute("type", "home"),
    "555-555-5555"),
new XElement("Phone",
    new XAttribute("type", "work"),
    "555-555-6666")
);

IEnumerable<XElement> elList =
    from el in cust.Descendants("Phone")
    select el;
foreach (XElement el in elList)
    Console.WriteLine((string)el.Attribute("type"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It I used Selman22's code and it worked fine. :)