# Get all attributes from the xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

Is there a way to get all the attributes from the xml file?
XML file :

```
<xml>
<level1>
<login Val=“true”><\login>
<inval>hello<\inval>
<\level1>
<level2 name=“Lara”>
<input place =“VKK”> teddy string <\input>
<\level2>
```

I’m looking to get the xmlatributecollection which contains
Val true
Name Lara
Place VKK

Also is it possible to get all the attributes in the child element ( element <level2 above )using
childelement.attributes
?
When I do this it only returns :
Name Lara

But I’m expecting it to return :
Name Lara
Place VKK

Is it possible ? Please share ideas . Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all attributes in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091107/get-all-attributes-in-xml)

Comment: Yes I tried that but dint work in my case

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Just elaborated the question by adding more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, your xml does not look right to me, anyway, let's assume it is something like this:

```
string xml = @"
<xml>
<level1>
    <login Val=""true""></login>
    <inval>hello</inval>
</level1>
<level2 name=""Lara"">
    <input place=""VKK""> teddy string </input>
</level2>
</xml>";
```

You can get all attributes with corresponding names and values like this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var attributes = doc.Descendants()
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => (string)x);
```

The result will be a dictionary with values:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Val | true |
| name | Lara |
| place | VKK |

DotNetFiddle example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zBbM3Y

Comment: Thanks! 
In my case it has duplicate keys also so when I try the above suggested way it says ‘an item with the same key has already been added’

Comment: @Lara In that case you can use different data structures, like `List<MyAttributes>()` by constructing that list instead of using `ToDictionary()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDocument class for this purpose

```
using System.Xml.Linq
```

The XDocument class contains the information necessary for a valid XML document, which includes an XML declaration, processing instructions, and comments.

You only have to create XDocument objects if you require the specific functionality provided by the XDocument class.

```
var path="";//your xml file path
var xDocLoad = XDocument.Load(path);

var allAttributes = xDocLoad.Descendants()
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes())
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => (string)x);
```